# Why can I not access this JS function ? Undefined is not a function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, dom-events

This is probably pretty stupid but it's been bugging me for a little while now. Trying to get something going with AngularJS and this is killing me.

Within a callback I have something like so:

```
var xyz = {
  "modA"  : null,
  "modB"  : null,
  "modC"  : null
}
```

I then attach some methods as well...

```
xyz.setModA = function(elementId) {

  var someConfig = {};
  // attach some kind of event callback on stateChange
  someConfig.events.onStateChange = this.helper;

  this.modA = new someObject(someConfig);      

}

xyz.setModC = function(vars) {
    ....
}

xyz.helper = function(event) {
  ....
  this.setModC(vars);
}
```

When the state of the modA object we instantiated changes then the onStateChange event occurs and **correctly** fires the *xyz.helper* method I have but then I instantly get an *Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function* ? For some reason it's not seeing the setModC method now when the event fires?

Comment: Wouldn't `this.setModC = 'something';` in `xyz.helper` blow away your `setModC` method?

Comment: @Cory Well seen. It's not current OP's bug but it could be the next one...

Comment: @Cory well seen indeed! Helper should've had this.setModC(cars); as the call which my real code actually has.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The context (`this`) in the event handler isn't the desired object.

To ensure the right context, change

```
someConfig.events.onStateChange = this.helper;
```

to

```
someConfig.events.onStateChange = this.helper.bind(this);
```